# Don't understand this "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute" even though it is imported it right before

Tags: python, class, module

I tried finding a solution here but had no luck. I had a piece of code that was working fine, but then I refactored things elsewhere and it broke this code for some reason. Here is example code that is causing the error:

```
try:
    import a.b.c.d
    CustomClass = a.b.c.d.MyClass
except ImportError:
    CustomClass = OtherClass

class MyClass(CustomClass):
    """Docstring"""
```

This is placed in the file `d.py`.  The `import` gives no error and never goes into that `except` block, but when I try to assign `CustomClass` I get the exception: `'module' object has no attribute 'd'`.

However, if I use the following code it works:

```
try:
    from a.b.c.d import MyClass
    CustomClass = MyClass
except ImportError:
    CustomClass = OtherClass

class MyClass(CustomClass):
    """Docstring"""
```

What could be causing the first code to produce the error but the second snippet to work? (Note: There are blank `__init__.py` files throughout the directory structure)

**Edit:** I just figured out that the second code is working because it gets thrown into the `except` block and goes through. So why doesn't the first set of code throw the `ImportError`?

Comment: How can you import `d` in module `d` and use `MyClass` before it is defined? This just doesn't make sense why you would think it would work, and what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want `MyClass` to have `MyClass` as a base?

Comment: This actually comes from auto-generated code that converts schemas to python. So  I actually have the same question as to why we want to do that. But to solve this particular problem, it seems the import a.b.c.d is not throwing an import error, so the subsequent use of the class causes the attribute error. Doesn't quite make sense to me how that would be the case.

Comment: Please [edit] you question and show the directory and file layout. How is the `d.py` module being executed—i.e. where's the code that's trying to use the `a` package?